# SailsJS Error: Cannot find module 'sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/deferred'

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Whenever I start `SailsJS` I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/deferred'
```

Tests are not runnable because whenever it try to lift sails for test, it gets an error and stops there.

Please help.

Comment: I checked the folder sails/node_modules/, there is no module waterline installed, while there should be. Did I do anything wrong when installing sails?

Comment: Is waterline defined in the dependencies section of sails/package.json? Did you get any errors while installing?

Comment: No waterline is not in package.json. I got some errors while installing but after I run "sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make" those install errors are gone. But the error is still there, waterline is not installed in the sails/node_modules.

Comment: I'm running node v0.12.7 on nvm, node-gyp 3.0.3, Linux Mint 17.1

Comment: Did you reinstall sails? You might even have to reinstall nodejs, because normally you run "sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make" before installing nodejs.

Comment: I'm having the same issue today. Used to work before.

Comment: npm does a lot of cleanup as of version 3 that hasn't been there before. Because of that it will not install `waterline` into the `sails` module directly, but one level higher. Open an issue and look for a more recent version of you hooks, generators, plugins, etc.

Answer (score 2):

first you try reinstall sails but if you don't, can add en package.json in dependencies: "waterline": "~0.10.26", save file y later run npm install inside you project folder, this should install waterline

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but runnin `npm install --prefix ./node_modules/sails waterline` command it works